# Stack Overflow user thumbnail is skewed - object-fit: cover;

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

This makes me cringe:

[image]

Can we put an `object-fit: cover` style on that user image please?

Comment: Related, on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189378/image-on-my-profile-always-gets-truncated/189458#189458

Comment: `object-fit: contain` would make more sense... No point in having the edges cut off. (Also, wow. I answered the question Pang linked to. I have absolutely no memory of that.)